# listen for gamepad connection and input

Tags: javascript, gamepad-api

I would like to provide gamepad support for my web application. This application is a socket client (using socket.io) and it should also being able to deal with gamepad input.

So when plugging in a gamepad via USB or Bluetooth I would like to fire an event, same for input. I was hoping that the [Gamepad API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Gamepad_API/Using_the_Gamepad_API) would solve it. Unfortunately it didn't.

I created this example

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  window.addEventListener("gamepadconnected", e => {
    console.log("connected gamepad");
  });

  window.addEventListener("gamepaddisconnected", e => {
    console.log("disconnected gamepad");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I plug in my XBox360 controller but unfortunately no event was fired. Am I missing something?

I use Chrome Version 76.0.3809.132 (Official Build) on Manjaro Linux (64-bit)

When running `navigator.getGamepads()` in the console I get this result `GamepadList {0: null, 1: null, 2: null, 3: null, length: 4}`

And btw. of course my controller is working on other applications e.g. games :)

---

**Update**

I installed Firefox 68.0.1 (64-bit) and it worked... but Chromium seems to struggle

Comment: What browser do you test on?

Comment: Hey, I'm using chrome

Comment: Hey, I was messing around with my Logitech G29 and Twin joystick and these events triggered without any problem on my Chrome(78.0.3904.108).
Is the controller recognized by the system? What is your OS?
Try running navigator.getGamepads() in the console when the gamepad is connected.

Comment: Hey :) I updated my post .. unfortunately it didn't help..

Comment: Have you read this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839310/html5-gamepad-api-on-chrome?

Comment: This is working for me perfectly on Firefox 70.0.1 on Arch Linux with an Xbox 360 USB gamepad. Does your controller work in other applications?

Comment: Ok I installed Firefox 68.0.1 (64-bit) and it worked there ...

Comment: Did you tried https://github.com/thinkpixellab/PxGamepad  try to register first than bind all events with window

Comment: As mentioned above, you need to press a gamepad button before Gamepad API will expose any information about connected gamepads. This includes gamepadconnected events. Info about connected devices can be used to fingerprint the user, so to protect your privacy, Chrome won't tell the page about your gamepads unless you're actually using one of them.

Answer (score 1):

##### TLDR

1. Refresh gamepad status in a loop and build your own events.
2. Remind players to press button on their gamepad to get started.

---

I wrote a little experiment with the Gamepad API, which I have [running on thepointless.com](https://www.thepointless.com/experimental/raw-gamepad-api/). The [full source is available on Github](https://github.com/svidgen/www.thepointless.com/blob/master/src/routes/experimental/raw-gamepad-api/index.js).

Essentially, my experiment does the following in a loop and just prints the output to the screen:

```js
JSON.stringify(
    [...navigator.getGamepads()]
    .filter(p => p)
    .map(pad => ({
        index: pad.index,
        id: pad.id,
        mapping: pad.mapping,
        axes: pad.axes,
        buttons: [...pad.buttons].map(b => ({
            pressed: b.pressed,
            touched: b.touched,
            value: b.value
        })),
        vibrationActuator: pad.vibrationActuator
    })),
    null,
    2
);
```

In my writeup, I've noted a few things that I anticipate will be generally helpful for working with the API. But, of more relevance to the OP:

1. The event listeners are a little unreliable.
2. Gamepads are not accessible via `navigator.getGamepads()` until a gamepad button is pressed.
3. The gamepad objects returned by `navigator.getGamepads()` are not "live"; you actually need to re-fetch them to gate latest axis and button status.

For those reasons, and particularly because you always need to query `navigator.getGamepads()` to refresh button/axes statuses *anyway*, any serious work I do with the API will always re-query for gamepads in my game loop, then check statuses, and instruct users to press a gamepad button if gamepads can't be found. If I need "events", I'll build out my own.

I would suggest others do that same.